# JAVA_OPTS/CATALINA_OPTS parameters not working with docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I build my image using below Dockerfile:

```
FROM java:jre-alpine
WORKDIR /target
ADD /target/test.jar test.jar
RUN sh -c 'touch /test.jar'
ENTRYPOINT ["java","/target/test.jar"]
```

And in my docker-compose.yml I have specified:

```
environment:
    - CATALINA_OPTS=-Xmx256m -Xms128m
```

However when I use docker stats to check the memory usage, my docker container consumes much more memory than 256m.

BUT If I specify the JVM parameter in Dockerfile directly(see below), then docker stats shows the correct number:

```
FROM java:jre-alpine
WORKDIR /target
ADD /target/test.jar test.jar
RUN sh -c 'touch /test.jar'
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Xmx512m","/target/test.jar"]
```

Could you give me some hints? I do not want to hardcode the -Xmx parameter in Dockerfile.

Comment: Your syntax for passing an environment variable is correct. You can run `docker-compose run yourservice env` to verify the environment variables are set as expected. I'd also recommend upgrading to the [openjdk](https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk/) image since the java image is deprecated. If you're still having issues, I expect the problem is java rather than docker.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I ended up like this:

- When I build the image, I specify in the Dockerfile:

  `ENTRYPOINT exec java $JAVA_OPTS -jar /target/test.jar`
- And then in the docker-compose.yml, I specify:

`environment:
  - JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx128m -Xms128m`

Answer (score 0):

When we have java opts such as `-Djetty.http.port=9900` we can put the env variable in quotes

```yaml
    environment:
      - "JAVA_OPTS=-Djetty.http.port=9900"
```

[source](https://www.jrebel.com/blog/preparing-docker-compose-environment)

Answer (score -2):

I ran into this you need to use : instead of =-

For example

```
environment:
     JAVA_OPTS: "-Ddatabase.url=xxx -Dsolr.url=xxx"
     CATALINA_OPTS: "-Ddatabase.url=xxx -Dsolr.url="
```

Oh and you don't need the hyphen at the start of the key part of the enviroment name

Comment: You can pass environment variables with either syntax, both are valid. I've defaulted to a list with `=` due to the syntax for passing constraints.